# How to link to Heroku app on correct port?

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, port, admin

I have a Oython app. It's a single script with `aiohttp`. I have a `requirements.txt` and `Procfile`. My deploy stage finishes successfully, but I can't understand how to open app with correct port.

My app listens to Heroku `PORT` env.

Heroku logs returns:

```
2019-04-19T13:34:44.150477+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user 
doubledare704@gmail.com
2019-04-19T13:34:44.150477+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 1b35a335 by user 
doubledare704@gmail.com
2019-04-19T13:34:45.357983+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from 
crashed to starting
2019-04-19T13:34:48.854124+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with 
command `python index.py`
2019-04-19T13:34:49.473879+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from 
starting to up
2019-04-19T13:34:51.167617+00:00 app[worker.1]: ======== Running on 
http://0.0.0.0:10303 ========
2019-04-19T13:34:51.167652+00:00 app[worker.1]: (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2019-04-19T13:34:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-04-19T13:35:05.578025+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No 
web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=google-adschecker- 
704.herokuapp.com request_id=8a85c812-a4b9-4d8f-98f6-91a8ff557594 
fwd="93.170.115.160" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-19T13:35:05.888452+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No 
web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=google- 
adschecker-704.herokuapp.com request_id=a7be2157-523c-4d00-9a26-a68e7d40e1fd 
fwd="93.170.115.160" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

H14 error says about dynos, but I've turned on 1 dyno. How to switch all HTTP requests to that port? Or how to manage settings on Heroku?

Here is my `Procfile`:

```
worker: python index.py
```

Comment: What's in your `Procfile`?

Comment: @Chris, it's just "worker: python index.py". Index.py contains aiohttp mini-server code, with 1 main handler. So it runs index py, creates python http server with Heroku PORT env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Workers can't receive network requests from the internet](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#the-web-process-type):

> A Heroku app’s `web` process type is special: it’s the only process type that can receive external HTTP traffic from Heroku’s routers. If your app includes a web server, you should declare it as your app’s `web` process.

Change your main process type from `worker` to `web` by modifying your `Procfile` like so:

```
web: python index.py
```